# Solutions about MySQL Syntax Error about server versions?

Tags: sql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I am having a problem about SQL syntax. I have a query and I got error 1064. I tried some different ways but could not find the right solution. Here is my query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM
                (SELECT id, category_id, @row_number := IF(@prev = category_id, @row_number + 1, 1) AS row_number, @prev := category_id
                FROM posts
                JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @row_number := 0) AS vars
                WHERE posts.is_scheduled = 0 AND posts.visibility = 1 AND posts.status = 1
                ORDER BY category_id, created_at DESC
                ) AS table_posts
                WHERE row_number <= 10";
```

And the error I got:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'row_number, @prev := category_id FROM posts JOIN' at line 2
>
> SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, category_id, @row_number := IF(@prev =
> category_id, @row_number + 1, 1) AS row_number, @prev := category_id
> FROM posts JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @row_number := 0) AS vars WHERE
> posts.is_scheduled = 0 AND posts.visibility = 1 AND posts.status = 1
> ORDER BY category_id, created_at DESC ) AS table_posts WHERE
> row_number <= 10

Any help

Comment: Avoid using variables (like `@prev`) since they are obsolete. They were marked as deprecated in MySQL 5.7, but they still worked. Now in MySQL 8.x they are gone for good.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.  Assigning variables in `select` statements is deprecated in the more recent versions of MySQL.